# Append Textarea with Cake PHP using Ajax

Tags: cakephp

Quick questions
Is there Way to Append a textarea using Cakephp

view code:

```
<?php echo $ajax->link(   
     $qnote['Qnote']['subject'],
     array(
         'controller' => 'qnotes',
         'action' => 'view', $qnote['Qnote']['id']
 ),
     array( 'update' => 'Textarea_id')
 ); 
?>
```

controller Code:

```
    function view($id = null) {  
    $this->Qnote->id = $id;
    $this->set('qnote', $this->Qnote->read());

}
```

the above code Pulls the information But Replaces the entire Text in the textarea. 
Is there a way I can just append the textarea with out removing the existing text in the textarea

if possible can somebody point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the result of your AJAX request to a hidden field and then having it execute and on page javascript function to simply slap the values from the hidden field to the visible text area.

The AJAX helper lets your specify callback functions, so something *like* this should work:

```
<?php echo $ajax->link(   
     $qnote['Qnote']['subject'],
     array(
         'controller' => 'qnotes',
         'action' => 'view', $qnote['Qnote']['id']
 ),
     array( 'update' => 'Textarea_id_hidden', "complete" => "concat_fields()" )
 ); 
?>
```

and then the JavaScript in the View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function concat_fields() {
    $('#Textarea_id').val( $('#Textarea_id').val() . $('#Textarea_id_hidden').val() );
  }
</script>
```

Note: My JavaScript example above assumes you're using JQuery, changes will need to be made if you're not.

Comment: Well Cake's AJAX Helper doesn't have a built in "append" ability. You could probably get away with removing the "update" functionality all together as the ajax $response object will get passed to the "complete" callback function, then you could concat from there. Either way, you're going to need on-page JavaScript to make it work.